# How to find email messages by categories using the Office 365 API?

Tags: rest, office365

I am using the REST API for Office 365 and want to be able to find messages based on categories assigned to them.

There is a [Categories property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#ResourcesMessage), but it is a collection, and I can't figure out how to use it in the $filter parameter.

I want a URL such as this, although I know parts of this are fictional:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=IsRead eq false and Categories contains 'Blue Category'&$select=Subject,Sender,DateTimeReceived,DateTimeLastModified,Categories
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possible, unfortunately. We're working to add more features to the APIs, so stay tuned!